# How to save a histogram from command line in R

Tags: r, save, histogram, virtual-machine

I am trying to save a histogram to file in R from my Virtual Machine.

I use the following R code:

```
> pdf("graph1.pdf")
> hist(nchar(as.character(m1$qf)),main="First name search 11-14 and 11-15",
  xlab="length of     name")
> dev.off()
null device 
      1
```

I get the response: `null device 1`

If I just run the `hist(nchar(as.character(m1$qf)),main="First name search 11-14 and 11-15",xlab="length of name")` in the command line I see the correct histogram.

But when saved to pdf, I get something that looks something like this:

```
ET
BT
/F2 1 Tf 0.00 12.00 -12.00 0.00 41.76 160.01 Tm (500000) Tj
ET
BT
/F2 1 Tf 0.00 12.00 -12.00 0.00 41.76 249.50 Tm (1000000) Tj
ET
BT
/F2 1 Tf 0.00 12.00 -12.00 0.00 41.76 342.32 Tm (1500000) Tj
ET
Q q 59.04 73.44 414.72 371.52 re W n
0.000 0.000 0.000 RG
0.75 w
[] 0 d
1 J
1 j
10.00 M
74.40 87.20 16.00 156.65 re S
90.40 87.20 16.00 20.71 re S
106.40 87.20 16.00 86.75 re S
```

That's not the histogram I was expecting.  How do I save a histogram to file?

Comment: The code you posted should save the histogram into a pdf file in your current working directory.  You can check your working directory by using the function getwd().  Do you not get the pdf saved?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: To see files in your current directory, run a dir()

Comment: What VM are you running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are new to plotting in R, I recommend getting an early start on [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/)

```
library(ggplot2)
data=data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
plot=qplot(x, data=data, geom="histogram") 
ggsave(plot,file="graph1.pdf")
```

Comment: I'll admit to being an old fogy who all too often uses the basic `plot` stuff, but ggplot and ggplot2 are absolutely the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

### R, Rscript, save histogram to file like: `foobar.png`:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(PlantGrowth)
png("foobar.png")
hist(PlantGrowth$weight)
dev.off()
```

Which produces a `foobar.png` in the same directory as the R script which contains the below image (provided you open it up in an image editor, not a word processor):

[image]

Comment: library(ggplot2) is not required.